# Display system information

Tags: hardware, configuration

I would like output akin to that of OSX's system_profiler (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/system_profiler.8.html)

On Ubuntu, I have to string a few utilities togeter: `uname -a`, `lshw`, `ifconfig`, etc... and then extract the list of installed software packages...

Is there a single, simple *facade* to getting **human readable** system info from the CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about such command but here a two useful commands that you'll love to use:

You may use a tool called **hwinfo** Which gives u a great list of your hardware(hdd,usb, monitor ,netwrok ,etc...)

Also it can be used to generate a system overview log which can be later  used  for support.

To install **hwinfo**

```
sudo apt-get install hwinfo
```

To use just type `hwinfo` in terminal but its better to redirect to a file to read

```
hwinfo > MYhardware.txt
```

To know the packages you have in your system you can use `dpkg --get-selections`

to redirect

```
dpkg --get-selections > installed-software
```